# Subscriber receives 0 value

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am publishing the pose from a node and receiving it another node. For some reason the subscriber is always getting a 0 value. Below is the ROS_INFO output of both the published message and the subscribed message.

```
[ INFO] [1467443650.648643683]: 0.174000    -0.289000     -0.275000

[ INFO] [1467443634.965920060]: 0.000000      0.000000       0.000000
```

This is a code snippet of the callback function where I am ROS_INFOing the message.

```
void BaseModule::KinematicsPoseMsgCallback( manipulator_base_module_msgs::KinematicsPose msg) 
{   
    if( enable == false )
        return;
    ROS_INFO("%f      %f       %f", msg.pose.position.x, msg.pose.position.y, msg.pose.position.z);
    Robotis->kinematics_pose_msg = msg;
```

Does anyone know why this might be the case?
Please tell me if you need any more information to solve this problem. Thanks.

Edit:
These are the publisher messages:

```
ros::Publisher k_i = n.advertise<manipulator_base_module_msgs::KinematicsPose>("kinematics_input", 10);
manipulator_base_module_msgs::KinematicsPose kin;
kin.pose.position.x = 0.174;
kin.pose.position.y = -0.289;
kin.pose.position.z = -0.275;
k_i.publish(kin);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238637/subscriber-receives-0-value/) by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-07-02**:
How do you publish the messages? What does rostopic echo show? [BTW: if( enable == false ) -> if (not enable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> void BaseModule::KinematicsPoseMsgCallback( manipulator_base_module_msgs::KinematicsPose msg)
> ```

```
{
  [..]
}
```

I'm not sure, but it could be that you are seeing the behaviour you report because you setup your callback to get a `KinematicsPose` instance *by value*, instead of *by reference*.

Could you try changing the callback to:

```
void BaseModule::KinematicsPoseMsgCallback( manipulator_base_module_msgs::KinematicsPoseConstPtr& msg)
```

that should probably make it work the way you expect.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0